# How to put line when td table value extend to another page TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

Good day sir, Im a newbie programmer. I would like to know how to put a line if the td extend to another page? I attach the image what is my problem. Sorry if my english not fluent.[image]

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846164/tcpdf-html-table-and-page-breaks

Comment: we dont have same problem... in my problem i want to put a line when the td value extend to another page..

Comment: in my 2nd column it was a description, the link u send is just prevents the table rows from ever breaking apart.. the td in my image cannot put this in one page

Comment: try adding an attribute on <td> like this.. <td nobr='true'>

Comment: nobr just prevent the td breaking apart... sample sir if you have a td value that display in 3 pages... nobr parin?...

Comment: nobr='true' JUST CAN advise for some short value... if you can see his sample rather than mine... we dont have same problem... all i want to put line every page